# How to configure store logs to application folder in Asp Net Core?

Tags: logging, asp.net-core, .net-core

Where `Asp.Net Core` stored log file that `ILogger` write ?

Is it any standard way to change log files location ?

I don't want to use any pacakges like https://www.nuget.org/packages/serilog.extensions.logging.file

Comment: Which `ILogger` method are you calling?

Comment: LogInformation for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Built-in logging providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging#built-in-logging-providers) for `ASP.NET Core` applications are:

- [Console](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging#console)
- [Debug](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging#debug)
- [EventSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging#eventsource)
- [EventLog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging#eventlog)
- [TraceSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging#tracesource)
- [Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging#appservice)

None of these classes can be used for logging to the file by default.
However, you can use [tracing listener](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging#tracesource), which can be set up for file usage, like this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app,
    IHostingEnvironment env,
    ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory
        .AddDebug();

    // add Trace Source logging
    var testSwitch = new SourceSwitch("sourceSwitch", "Logging Sample");
    testSwitch.Level = SourceLevels.Warning;
    loggerFactory.AddTraceSource(testSwitch,
        new TextWriterTraceListener("MyLogName.txt"));
```

As you can see, here you can filter your messages, right now it will write down all the warnings and higher messages. Also you can setup a [filter for listener](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracelistener.filter.aspx):

```
var testSwitch = new SourceSwitch("sourceSwitch", "Logging Sample");
var listener = new TextWriterTraceListener("MyLogName.txt");
listener.Filter = new SourceFilter("YourFilterName");
loggerFactory.AddTraceSource(testSwitch, listener);
```

In consumer classes this can be used as:

```
logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("YourFilterName");
```

Related articles:

- [Logging in ASP.NET Core](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1073028/ASP-NET-Logging-using-Trace-Listeners-and-How-to-F) on CodeProject
- MSDN article [Essential .NET - Logging with .NET Core](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt694089.aspx)

Comment: There is one more logging provider -- DiagnosticSource https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource/src/DiagnosticSourceUsersGuide.md